# Opening and saving word doc in vb.net - error when visibility turned off

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

I am opening a word document and saving it as html with the following code. If i set the objWord.Visible = False , i get an error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A1098 , which i believe indicates there is nothing to open.
 If i set objWord.Visible = True, the code runs properly, but i dont want the end user to see word in action. Would appreciate any help.

thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim objWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
    If Not (fUpload.HasFile) Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Please choose file to upload"
    Else
        Try
            Dim strFileName As String = fUpload.FileName
            Dim strSep As String() = fUpload.FileName.Split("."c)
            Dim arrLength As Integer = strSep.Length - 1
            Dim strExt As String = strSep(arrLength).ToString().ToUpper()
            'Save the uploaded file to the folder

            strPathToUpload = Server.MapPath("Uploaded")
            strPathToConvert = Server.MapPath("WordToHtml")
            Dim FileName As Object = (strPathToUpload & "\") + fUpload.FileName

            Dim FileToSave As Object = (strPathToConvert & "\") + Left(fUpload.FileName, Len(fUpload.FileName) - 4) & ".htm"
            If strExt.ToUpper().Equals("DOC") Then
                fUpload.SaveAs((strPathToUpload & "\") + fUpload.FileName)
                lblMessage.Text = "File uploaded successfully"

                'open file in word
                objWord.Documents.Open(FileName, missing, [readOnly], missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, isVisible)

                objWord.Visible = False 'error occures here if False

                Dim oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = objWord.ActiveDocument

                If oDoc.Application.Version = "12.0" Then ' Word 2007 version
                    oDoc.SaveAs2(FileToSave, fltDocFormat, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
                Else ' word 2003 version
                    oDoc.SaveAs(FileToSave, fltDocFormat, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
                End If

            Else
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid file selected!"
            End If

            'Close/quit word 
            objWord.Quit(missing, missing, missing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            objWord.Quit(missing, missing, missing)
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting Visible to false before opening the document?

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
Dim objWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass = CreateoBject("Word.Application")
```

Generally, I've never known word automation objects to be visible when you create them this way UNLESS Word was already loaded.

Also, you appear to be passing an ISVISIBLE argument to the DOCUMENTS.OPEN function, but I can't tell what it's value is. If it's FALSE, the document should be loaded in a hidden window the user can't see even if Word was already open.

Comment: Thanks drventure - it was the ISVISIBLE that was causing the problem. I got it working on localhost, but when i download to doscountasp.net i found out that the server has to have word installed - which they don't. Is there a work around for this or is it just not possible to save a word doc as html?